# HTML - is it possible to trigger a direct phone call from a website without displaying the phone number on a mobile device?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-website

I want to trigger a phone call through my website but I don't want it to be displayed on the Phone call native App. I used href="tel:555676876" but it will redirect me to the Call App instead of calling straight up.
Is there a javascript code for this apart from "window.open('tel:*901%23');"

Comment: This won't ever be possible (hopefully...)

Comment: I'm sure a lot of criminals would love to be able to set up websites that caused mobile phones to dial premium rate telephone numbers without the user knowing or confirming the call.

Answer (score 2):

No.

If this was possible, it would have been quite a security risk, as web sites could start unsolicited calls to fraud numbers.

Answer (score -1):

Hiding phone number may not be possible.

`<a href="tel:5551234567">Call</a>`

One click should open the phone dialler and input the number to be called.

Comment: This will display the phone number being dialed.

Comment: Yes. While making a call, you are using android's native feature. Hence you do not have control on hiding phone number. Even if it was allowed, it could have been risky and caused security issues.

Comment: I completely agree. I'm just pointing out that your answer, therefore, doesn't satisfy the OP's requirement, which is to hide the number. His requirement is, though, unreasonable and impossible.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. There is no possible solution for this question.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. much appreciated